# what the meaning of plus operator in this JQUERY scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask mean of plus operator in this script +i+ in the follow:

```
i=0;
// next line in scripts write this code :
$('.container[data-id='+i+']').hide(); // +i+ what the meaning of it
```

Need Help thanks a TON

Comment: is the above code written by you or its there like that??

Comment: while giving dynamic values in between strings we use somethinglike var finalval= dynamic1 + "test" + dynamic2

Comment: @another programmer write like this and it works, it reference to variable like in the for loop statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is used to concatenate strings

In this case, it is used to concatenate the value of `i`between **.container[data-id=**  and **]**

Assuming that i is storing some value eg 0, then this will be evaluated to

```
$('.container[data-id=0]').hide();
```

Comment: +i+ not + ( i can't understand it coz it reference to variable who declare on top of script

Comment: @Joko Wandiro: It's not incrementing `i`, it's concatenating it to two different strings.

`'a' + i + 'b'` evaluates to `'a0b'` or `'a1b'` or `'a55b'`, depending on the value of `i`

Answer (score 3):

This will concatenate the value in the variable `i` with the remaining string.

See [**Concatenating strings**](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#conc)

Answer (score 2):

```
+ is used for string concantination 

var test= "hello" + "world";// gives helloworld
```

it is used for adding values also

```
var c= a+ b// if a=10 and b=20 it gives 30
```

Answer (score 2):

The `+` operator in JavaScript is used for both Arithmetic and String operations.
If both operands are of `Number` type, the result is the sum. If either of the operands is not a number, then both will be converted to `String` and concatenated. It should be used with care.